# sigmoid + binary_crossentropy and flow_from_directory

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

If we want to use sigmoid + binary_crossentropy for multilabel classification (like each image can have many tags) in Keras, `flow_from_directory` [[1]](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) can't be used? and we need to write custom batch generator?

Comment: What makes you worried? How are these two related?

Comment: @Maxim Looks like it support only one label per image, because each image is stored in separate folder which have class name.